# how to Enumerate local fonts in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, fonts, local

I heard about silverlight 4 can use local fonts. So, is there a way fo enumerate them? I just want to have them shown into a listbox.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`SystemTypefaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fonts.systemtypefaces(v=VS.95).aspx) static property of the `System.Windows.Media.Fonts` class.  This provides a collection go `Typeface` objects listing the set of fonts found in the system font folder.

Comment: Items from Fonts.SystemTypefaces have one method: bool TryGetGlyphTypeface(out GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface); yielding two properties: FontFileName and Version. How do I use this? How do I get the font family name? This is for SL 4.

Comment: @Peet: Consider posting this comment as a question with a little more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with the same issue.

I ended up using [`Fonts.SystemFontFamilies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fonts.systemfontfamilies.aspx) on the SERVER (in the PresentationCore dll), and then sending a list of strings (from the `Source` property) to the Silverlight app. On my machine, sending 236 font names with a service call is about 8 KB, which is not that bad.

Yes, the client might not have all the fonts installed on his machine, but this is the best I could find.